# Three.js, Imported Camera from Collada can not look at an object scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

Im struggling with Three.js to understand how Collada Animation workout ! 
I got an animation with a moving camera in 3Dsmax, and i exported the scene into Collada.

```
loader.load( ColladaName, function ( collada ) {

    model = collada.scene;
    model.updateMatrix();
    animations = collada.animations;
    kfAnimationsLength = animations.length;
    model.scale.x = model.scale.y = model.scale.z = 0.001; // 1/8 scale, modeled in cm
    document.getElementById('preload').style.opacity = '0';

    callback()

} );
```

I capture the camera object from the collada :

```
 model.traverse(function(child) {

    if (child instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera) {

        camera = child;
        camera.near = 1;
        camera.fov = 30;
        camera.castShadow = true;
    }

    if (child instanceof THREE.SpotLight) {

        child.castShadow = true;

        child.shadowBias = 0.02;

        child.shadowCameraNear = 1;
        child.shadowCameraFov = 60;
        child.intensity = 1.2;

        child.shadowMapWidth = 1024; // default is 1024
        child.shadowMapHeight = 1024; // default is 1024
        child.shadowDarkness = 0.06; // default is 512

    }

});

 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

Then i render it in my scene : 
   camera.lookAt(scene.position)
   renderer.render(scene, camera);

Everything show up, i can see my model, with my imported camera, but my camera doesnt look at the scene and doesnt reproduce the x-rotation like in my 3Dsm zoom in, and zoom out ! 
If i log the camera position it always show : 0,0,0. Better, if i log the model.children[0] position, wich correspond to the perspective camera imported into the collada, it always show 0,0,0

What am i doing wrong  ?

**EDIT 1 :**

I tried to set my camera matrix with the imported camera from the collada :

```
camera.matrixNeedsUpdate = true;
model.children[0].matrixNeedsUpdate = true;
model.children[0].lookAt(model.position)

camera.matrix.elements = model.children[0].matrix.elements
```

but no results unfortunately..

Comment: Can you upload your project somewhere? Or a reduced version?

Comment: I post it in 20mn ! thank you doob !

Comment: http://thxyoudoob.herokuapp.com/

There it is ! 

In my animation , the camera look at the object target ( wich is a children of the collada )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're doing a camera.lookAt() to a position that is in "local space".

Try doing this:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
vector.setFromMatrixPosition( object.matrixWorld );

camera.lookAt( vector );
```